# Using "$http.get" in ionic App, Response not get proper format

Tags: angularjs, ajax, ionic-framework

I am using "$http.get" for send request. My API response in browser, it returns what i want. But in Ionic App, it return HTML body tag text.

My Code is:

```
    var params = {
        email: 'test@gmail.com',
        password: '123'
    }

    $http.get("https://www.nepalivivah.com/API/index.php/accessapi/loginapi", { params: params }).then(function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }).error(function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
```

This is my AngularCode. When i run it in postman, it return valid response. But in Ionic App not Working.

Comment: "Not working" is too broad of a description. How is it not working? What are the errors? Is the data different that what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the **$http.get**, this should work.

```
var params = {
    email: 'test@gmail.com',
    password: '123'
}

$http.get("https://www.nepalivivah.com/API/index.php/accessapi/loginapi").then(function (data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}).error(function (err) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

However, in this case, what you are trying to do is to login into something. A **get** request will not work with this. You need to use **$http.post** at least in this case.

Comment: My API in GET method. I also try it with POST method. But it is not working. Same response received in POST method.

Comment: Maybe you need another parameter(s) for the **$http.post**